# PCA error in Matlab: svd did not converge

Tags: matlab, pca, svd

I was trying to do PCA on some matrix( approximately 2500 by 2500 floating points) using Matlab function [`pca`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pca.html). I tried some settings such as:

```
pca(data, 'Centered', true, 'NumComponents', numComponents)
```

but the error still comes up. 
I tried to use another method:

```
pca(data,'algorithm','als')
```

but it was extremely slow. Could anyone share some thoughts?

***Update:***
To be more specific, [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3uxorab6v6c7217/problematicPCAMatrix.mat) is the matlab matrix that pca function always gives errors, is there a problem with the matrix?

Comment: @RDizzl3: Can you explain the `0`? As far as I see the input parameters are X and any number parameter name/value pairs.

Comment: @Daniel, I didn't see any "0" from the question above, what do you mean?

Comment: There was a comment written by RDizzl3 which I did not understand. He deleted it.